# Do RPCs on Google Appengine support "wait with timeout"?

Tags: google-app-engine, urlfetch

I'm trying to implement the following logic on Google Appengine:

```
rpc = call_external_service(timeout=T)
rpc.wait(timeout=T/2)
if rpc.done:
   return rpc.result
rpc2 = call_backup_service(timeout=T/2)
finished_rpc = wait_any([rpc, rpc2], timeout=T/2)
return finished_rpc.result
```

That is, call a service (using `urlfetch`) with a timeout of T. If it doesn't finish in `T/2`, try calling a backup service and then wait for either of them to finish.

The problem is that the RPC mechanism doesn't seem to offer a "wait with timeout" primitive. That is, if I create an RPC with a deadline T, I can't say "wait for T/2 seconds and see if the RPC finished".

Has anyone a workaround for this?

---

**Edit**: @TarunLalwani posted a potential solution. The idea is to have a special handler which sleeps for a predetermined amount of time (something like `/sleep?delay=5`) and add that as second parameter to `UserRPC.wait_any`. Ie. something like:

```
rpc = call_external_service(timeout=T)
rpc2 = create_wait_rpc(timeout=T/2)
finished_rpc = wait_any([rpc, rpc2])
if finished_rpc == finished_rpc:
  return rpc.result
rpc2 = call_backup_service(timeout=T/2)
finished_rpc = wait_any([rpc, rpc2])
return finished_rpc.result
```

Unfortunately it seems that `UserRPC.wait_any` is implemented something like the following:

```
def wait_any(rpcs):
    last_rpc = rpcs[-1]
    last_rpc.wait()
    return last_rpc
```

That is, it always waits for the *last* RPC to finish, which is a problem in our case because if the initial call finishes in less than T/2 time, we would like to return the result immediately, rather than having to wait a minimum of T/2. I tested this with both the local `dev_appserver` and in production (the quick test code can be grabbed from https://github.com/cdman/gae-rpc-test).

This could still be made to work by using some extremely small timeout for `rpc2`, something like:

```
rpc = call_external_service(timeout=T)
end_time = time.time() + T/2
while time.time() < end_time:
    wait_any([rpc, create_wait_rpc(timeout=0.1)])
    if rpc.status == 2:
        return rpc.result
# else, call backup service
```

However, here I'm still artificially limiting my time resolution to 100ms (so if the initial call finishes in 230ms, we return the result only after 300ms) and I'll be spamming my logs with *a lot* of requests to `/sleep`. Also, this could increase the costs of running the project.

Alternatively, if there were some kind of no-op / low overhead RPC that could be passed in as the second parameter of `UserRPC.wait_any` to keep the event-loop moving, then this semi-busy-wait solution could perhaps possibly work :-)

---

**Edit 2**: I implemented the busy-waiting version using the asynchronous version of `memcache.get` from ndb. You can take a look at the source here: https://github.com/cdman/gae-rpc-test/blob/ndb-async/main.py

Theoretically this should be free (see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#other-resources), but still feels like a hack.

---

**Edit 3**: It looks like the following *should* work:

```
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import eventloop
# ...
ev = eventloop.get_event_loop()
while time.time() < end_time:
  ev.run1()
  if rpc.done():
    break
  time.sleep(0.001)
```

(that is run the eventloop explicitly, check the RPC and it's not done, sleep a little and retry)

Unfortunately the "run the eventloop" step just blocks until the urlfetch completes at a certain point :(

Comment: When you say `timeout` I assume you are using the `deadline` parameter?

Comment: @TarunLalwani - yes, I just wanted to keep it generic.

Comment: Posted my observations on the same, please have a look

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR;**

After digging through the source of python appengine sdk, below are my observations and take away.

**wait_any is not what it looks like**

When you use `wait_any` on 2 `RPCs` you would like the one that finished first but the logic of the same doesn't seem that way

```
assert iter(rpcs) is not rpcs, 'rpcs must be a collection, not an iterator'
finished, running = cls.__check_one(rpcs)
if finished is not None:
  return finished
if running is None:
  return None
try:
  cls.__local.may_interrupt_wait = True
  try:
    running.__rpc.Wait()
  except apiproxy_errors.InterruptedError, err:
    err.rpc._exception = None
    err.rpc._traceback = None
finally:
  cls.__local.may_interrupt_wait = False
finished, runnning = cls.__check_one(rpcs)
return finished
```

In the below line of code

```
finished, running = cls.__check_one(rpcs)
```

The code of method `__check_one` is like below

```
rpc = None
for rpc in rpcs:
  assert isinstance(rpc, cls), repr(rpc)
  state = rpc.__rpc.state
  if state == apiproxy_rpc.RPC.FINISHING:
    rpc.__call_user_callback()
    return rpc, None
  assert state != apiproxy_rpc.RPC.IDLE, repr(rpc)
return None, rpc
```

So it just checks if any one of them is already finished and if not then it returns the last one the in collection, the last `return None, rpc`

Then `wait_any` makes a call to `running.__rpc.Wait()`. So created a simple `sleep`/`delay` handler for the same

class SleepHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

```
def get(self):
    delay = float(self.request.get('delay')) if self.request.get('delay') else 10
    sleep(delay)
    self.response.status_int = 200
    self.response.write('Response delayed by {}'.format(delay))
```

And added below MainHandler to test the `deadline`

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # rpc = UserRPC('dummywait', 5, stubmap=MyStubMap)

        rpc = urlfetch.create_rpc(deadline=2.0)
        rpc2 = urlfetch.create_rpc(deadline=6.0)
        urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc, self.request.host_url + "/sleep?delay=1")
        urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc2, self.request.host_url + "/sleep?delay=5")
        try:
            print(datetime.now())
            finished = apiproxy_stub_map.UserRPC.wait_any([rpc, rpc2])
            print(finished.request.url_)
            print(datetime.now())
            i = 0
        except Exception as ex:
            print_exception(ex)
        # ... do other things ...
        try:
            print(datetime.now())
            result = finished.get_result()
            print(datetime.now())
            if result.status_code == 200:
                text = result.content
                self.response.write(text)
            else:
                self.response.status_int = result.status_code
                self.response.write('URL returned status code {}'.format(
                    result.status_code))
        except urlfetch.DownloadError:
            print(datetime.now())
            self.response.status_int = 500
            self.response.write('Error fetching URL')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/sleep', SleepHandler),
], debug=True)
```

So below are the points in above code

- `rpc` has a deadline of `2.0` sec and the actual request finishes in `1.0`
- `rpc2` has a deadline of `6.0` sec and the actual request finishes in `5.0`

Now ideally the expectation would be that we get `rpc` as finished task and the data displayed on url response. But the output is

[image: RPC response]

Now if we switch the order of `wait_any` arguments from

```
finished = apiproxy_stub_map.UserRPC.wait_any([rpc, rpc2])
```

to

```
finished = apiproxy_stub_map.UserRPC.wait_any([rpc2, rpc])
```

The output changes to below

[image: RPC wins]

So this means if you create a deadline of `T` and `T/2` then your minimal waiting time would always be `T/2` if you use that as the last parameter.

So whatever solutions you will try to solve this in google appengine they will still be dirty tricks. Now possible trick is to do intervals. Below one such sample

```
    T = 10.0
    # Deadline T
    rpc_main = urlfetch.create_rpc(deadline=T)

    # Deadline T/2
    rpc_backup = urlfetch.create_rpc(deadline=T / 2)

    urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc_main, self.request.host_url + "/sleep?delay=7")

    i = 0.0

    while i < T / 2:
        rpc_compare = urlfetch.create_rpc()
        urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc_compare, self.request.host_url + "/sleep?delay=0.5")

        finished = apiproxy_stub_map.UserRPC.wait_any([rpc_main, rpc_compare])
        i += 0.5
        if finished == rpc_main:
            break

    if finished != rpc_main:
        # we need to fire a backup request
        urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc_backup, self.request.host_url + "/sleep?delay=1")

        finished = apiproxy_stub_map.UserRPC.wait_any([rpc_backup, rpc_main])

    try:
        finished.get_result()
    except DeadlineExceededError as ex:
        # Rpc main finished with error then we need to switch to Backup request 
        finished = rpc_backup
```

Here we give `rpc_main` as priority instead of backup, even though backup would finish first in this case, we get response from `rpc_main`

[image: RPC Main]

Now if I change the RPC main to fall below deadline

```
    urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc_main, self.request.host_url + "/sleep?delay=20")
```

The output will change to

[image: RPC Backup wins]

So it shows both polling as well worst case wait scenario. This is the only possible workaround/implementation I have been able to workout looking at the original source code.

Comment: Thank you. So the underlying trick is to (a) create an other RPC aimed at an endpoint which delays sleeps for a certain time and (b) do a wait_any with both of the RPCs, but make sure to put whichever RPC you expect to finish first as first.

I've missed the second part when doing my experiments.

Comment: Follow up question: do you know of other RPCs I could use to wait a specific amount of time other than urlfetch? (perhaps I can use a datastore / memcache / etc RPC). It just seems silly (and potentially costly!) to issue an external URLfetch whenever I want to sleep a little.

Comment: This is not a external but a internal call within in the same handler. So I used a handler within the same project. But I am not sure of the costing impacts of the same, you can try and demo and see how it goes

Comment: I posted an edit to the question with some updates. I'm thinking that we're moving in the right direction but we're not there yet.

Comment: @GreyPanther, so the way I saw it works is that main code that runs actually makes a call back to the admin backend and speaks protobuffer  to the admin and request it to actually make the api call and the deadline. I have a possible workaround which I am exploring but I am not sure what is the impact of the same on parallel requests

Comment: Please see my latest edit - I managed to get a busy-wait version implemented, but I'm looking forward to checking out what you come up with!

Comment: I was actually looking at `google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py`, `encoded_response = self._server.Send(self._path, encoded_request)` you can send a `timeout` here. But I think the timeout may impact both the calls

Comment: @GreyPanther, I think I don't have a further update/workaround on this. Let me know how you want to take it forward, do you want me to update my answers with your findings or you want to make another answer?

Comment: I just accepted your answer because - while it did not give the definitive solution - it helped me a lot in clarifying my thinking and also I think I found an answer! I'll add an answer shortly.

Comment: Glad to hear that and waiting to see your answer as well :-)

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a workable solution - see the latest edit. And it also seems that while the memcache operations are not billed, there is definitely a quota on them and probably doing `memcache.get` aggresively in a loop will quickly lead to me exhausting the quote and the calls becoming rate-limited. I will try to follow up on this with Google Support.

Comment: Yeah keep us posted when your hear back from Google support. This is not easily achieve without a timer kind of a event, in case of Node you would just run a `setTimeout` to start at `T/2` and things become much more easier. But with Python it gets a bit tough

Comment: My Google contact just confirmed that this is not possible with Python 2.7 on Google AppEngine standard, however my use-case was noted and they are considering adding support for it :|

Comment: Thanks for the update @GreyPanther, hope they add it soon for you :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can set a custom request timeout by using the following urlfetch [function](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests?csw=1#setting_a_request_timeout):

`urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(value)`

Note that this function stores the new default deadline on a thread-local variable, so it must be set for each request, for example, in a custom middleware. Value parameter is the deadline in seconds for the operation; the default is a system-specific deadline (typically 5 seconds).

The actual implementation will depend on your language but once you set a custom timeout you can easily set a value of deadline/2 for your call to the backup service.

Comment: yes, I'm aware of that option (and I can even customize the timeout on a per-request basis). However using it makes me choose between:

(1) abandon the initial call after T/2 or (2) block for T time

What I want to do is to (1) start the initial call (2) check its status after T/2 time. if it isn't finished, DO NOT abort but rather launch a second request. (3) after an additional T/2 time check the status of both requests and if any of them finished, return the result. So the original call has at most T time to finish while the backup call has T/2 time to finish.

Comment: Also important for me: if any of the calls finish early, I would want to "wake up" early instead of blindly waiting for T or T/2 seconds - so that I can return the result ASAP.

Comment: This wont work, I have tested something will post my finding soon